# How do you cancel the onchange event from within the event

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, bootstrap-5

I have 2 bootstrap 5 multi-select dropdown lists that contain the same information and if an option is selected in one it can't be selected in the other.  I know this is a bad scenario but it's what the requirement is so bare with me.

This is the what I have so far -

```
$('#ddlOne').on('change', function (e) {
    if ($('#ddlTwo option[value=' + e.currentTarget.value + ']:selected').length > 0){
        alert("This ddlOne option has already been selected in ddlTwo.  Selection canceled...");
        //How to cancel the selection of the currentTarget
    }
});
```

Comment: You can always `return false` to cancel an event. You may want to `e.preventDefault()` up front too.

Comment: return false;         //didn't work
e.preventDefault();   //didn't work

Comment: You can try making the option disabled in the 2nd list if it's selected in the 1st, and vice versa. Element `<option>` supports a `disabled` property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option You could also even remove the option that shouldnt be selected, e.g. by storing the items in a JS array, if and when needed filter the array, then use that to generate the `<option>`s.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is what you want, Here is a simple demo with two dropdownlists, When the first one choose an option, The other one will disable the option which selected in the first one, Hope it can solve your issue.

```js
function TestA(a) {
  var b = document.getElementById("BB");
  for (j = 0; j < b.options.length; j++) {
    b.options[j].disabled = false
  }

  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a.options[i].selected) {
      for (j = 0; j < b.options.length; j++) {
        if (b.options[j].value == a.options[i].value && a.options[i].value != "Open this select menu") {
          b.options[i].disabled = true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


function TestB(a) {
  var b = document.getElementById("AA");
  for (j = 0; j < b.options.length; j++) {
    b.options[j].disabled = false
  }

  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a.options[i].selected) {
      for (j = 0; j < b.options.length; j++) {
        if (b.options[j].value == a.options[i].value && a.options[i].value != "Open this select menu") {
          b.options[i].disabled = true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<select class="form-select" multiple aria-label="multiple select example" id="AA" onchange="TestA(this)">
  <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">four</option>
  <option value="5">five</option>
</select>


<select class="form-select" multiple aria-label="multiple select example" id="BB" onchange="TestB(this)">
  <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">four</option>
  <option value="5">five</option>
</select>
```

[image: Demo]

Comment: Thanks, It's elegant but the user would submit a ticket because they would think it was broken even though they know the business rules.

Comment: Sorry, i can't get your point, Could you explain more details?

Comment: I need to be able to cancel the onchnage event or if there is an onselect event I can intercept the action there thus showing the error message an de-selecting the option.

Comment: In my answer, If user select the wrong options, they just need to select `Open this select menu`, Then the other dropdownlist will release the options which user select in the first dropdownlist, Do u want a button when user select the wrong options, They just need to click the button then the dropdownlist wil be restored?